# making clock in chrome app - setTimeout() returns error

Tags: javascript, time, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am making chrome app and wanted to have simple clock in fullscreen mode of application (so i cant see windows clock). I thought i'd trivial since javascript has all the functions to print out current date on the screen. I also made that in pure javascript (i mean in www apps not packaged apps). The problem occured when I wanted to call setTimeout() function - chrome doesnt let me do this and warns me with words:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
> not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
> Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem:
> chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly
> set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

My code looks like this:

```js
function display () {
    this.currentTimeTxt = "TIME: ";
    this.getCurrentTime = function () {
        var time = new Date()
        if ( time.getHours() < 10 ) { var hours = '0' + time.getHours() } else { var hours = time.getHours() }
        if ( time.getMinutes() < 10 ) { var minutes = '0' + time.getMinutes() } else { var minutes = time.getMinutes() }
        if ( time.getSeconds() < 10 ) { var seconds = '0' + time.getSeconds() } else { var seconds = time.getSeconds() }
        return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }
}
var display = new display();
setTimeout(console.log(display.getCurrentTime), 1000);
```

What is the proper way to make clock "ticking" every second in chrome packaged apps?

---- EDITED CODE:

```
function display () {
    this.currentTimeTxt = "TIME: ";
    this.getCurrentTime = function () {
        var time = new Date()
        if ( time.getHours() < 10 ) { var hours = '0' + time.getHours() } else { var hours = time.getHours() }
        if ( time.getMinutes() < 10 ) { var minutes = '0' + time.getMinutes() } else { var minutes = time.getMinutes() }
        if ( time.getSeconds() < 10 ) { var seconds = '0' + time.getSeconds() } else { var seconds = time.getSeconds() }
        setTimeout(function () { display.getCurrentTime}, 1000)
        return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        }
    }
var display = new display();
display.getCurrentTime()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you want `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` only executes once after the specified delay, while `setInterval` executes once every interval.

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` both take either a string (which is `eval`'d, generally a bad practice) or a function. The return value of `console.log` is not either of these. And `console.log` needs the return value of `display.getCurrentTime`, not the function itself, so remember to include the parentheses.

So you just need to pass in a function that gets the current time, and logs it.

It's common to pass `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`) an anonymous function, like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(display.getCurrentTime());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you for solving - interval and anonymous function was what i was looking for

Comment: `getCurrentTime` should not include the call to `setInterval` -- you want `setInterval` to call whatever code should execute periodically.

Answer (score 1):

instead of setTimeout(),
 [chrome.alarm API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) is encouraged to use.